# Calculating an estimate of KL Divergence using the samples drawn from distributions

Tags: machine-learning, probability, metric

Given two sets of samples drawn from two different distributions, is it computationally possible to get an estimate of KL-Divergence between the two distribution using these samples?

Here I am assuming the dimensionality of the two distributions is high (say *d*). To compute the estimate, we first need to discretize the entire space and then estimate probabilities based on the frequencies. Let us say, we discretize each dimension into *p* bins. Then the total number of grids in the space will be $p^d$. So we need to compute the probabilities of the two distributions for $p^d$ grids, which is exponential in time. Hence I assume we cannot compute an estimate of KL Divergence using the samples for any practical problem.

I wanted to check if this explanation is correct or if I am missing anything. Could someone assert if this rationale is correct?

Comment: If you know the distributions, you can fit them then calculate the divergence at points of your choosing, In any case regularization is advisable. I found this presentation, which gives a more detailed treatment: [Kullback-Leibler Divergence Estimation of Continuous Distributions](http://videolectures.net/ripd07_cruz_kld).

Comment: @Emre Right, but sometimes we don't know the distributions. Example: features extracted from a neural network. So in the case where we don't know the form of the distribution, we can't estimate KL-Divergence. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In that case you want a _nonparametric_ estimator; cf. e.g., [Nonparametric Divergence Estimation with Applications to Machine Learning on Distributions](https://dslpitt.org/uai/papers/11/p599-poczos.pdf).

Comment: @Emre I didn't know this. Thanks for the direction. I will check it.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this article](https://www.princeton.edu/~kulkarni/Papers/Journals/j068_2009_WangKulVer_TransIT.pdf). They use k-NN to interpolate the values of P(x) and Q(x), so that you can use the KL-divergence formula with 'approximated histograms'.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to discretize the space since KL divergence can be calculated for continuous spaces.

Yes - you can calculate the difference between samples using KL divergence.

Based on differences between samples, estimating a possible difference in populations is the core of [statistical inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_inference). It is a very complex issue.